# Epicor/Crystal Reports plan as, pull as or phantom

Tags: crystal-reports, epicorerp

I created a BOM report have everything set up in Epicor and Crystal Reports the way it should be except for listing if it is plan as, pull as or phantom. I think I need direction on this...I have scoured the web and googled and have not been successful in finding anything that was helpful to me.
Can anyone help steer me in the right direction?

Comment: What you've posted is that you want to display something in your BOM report, but you don't list how. Should it be a column? Do you want to sort by this property? Do you want to group by it?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling thanks for being on here and helping me along the way...I guess first things first is that I don't even know what plan as, pull as or phantom means. I just know that the report should list if it is a plan as, pull as or phantom. It also says feel free to list for top level if that makes the code easier...and they want it for both standard and costed versions.

Comment: Sounds like your question actually is more of a business logic one. I'm not familiar with those terms, other than a guess that they are inventory status types. Also, "top level" and or standard/costed also seem like business-specific terms.